# enp3s0 and wlp2s0 not found, ubuntu v16.04

Tags: ethernet

I can't see enp3s0 and wlp2s0 on ubuntu 16.04 , and I also don't see enp3s0 and wlp2s0 in GUI when I type #ifconfig
But I can see both when I type #ifconfig -a.So, I can't assign ip address on ethernet interface and I can't get internet. Please help me. :(

Answer (score 0):

In 16.04 NetworkManager.service or networking.service should bring up your devices at boot when

1. a cable is plugged into the ethernet interface enp3s0
2. or when the wifi-interface wlp2s0 is not being blocked by a killswitch on your laptop for example.

---

Things you could do:

1. **Check if NetworkManager and networking.service are up and running**
   `systemctl status NetworkManager.service && systemctl status networking.service`
2. You could **check** with `rfkill list` **if your wifi-interface is beeing hard or softblocked**. The output would look like this:

   ```
   0: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
   2: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: yes
   Hard blocked: no
   ```

   If the wifi-device would be Soft blocked you can unblock it by

```
rfkill ublock <device-number>
rfkill unblock 0 # in my case
```

If the device is Hard blocked it means that there is some killswitch on your laptop that prevents the wifi card from being up/online. Solution: Find the killswitch and press it.

3. **Bring up your device manually**. If you want to manually try to bring up you ethernet devices you can write:

```
ip link set <interface> up
ip link set enp3s0 up
ip link set wlp2s0 up
```

after that you could also assign ip's with `dhclient enp3s0` or `dhclient wlp2s0`

To assign ip's manually you can type:

```
ip addr add <ip>/<subnet> <broadcast ip> dev <interface>
ip addr add 192.168.1.101/24 broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev enp3s0
```

of course you have to set the ip's accordingly to your network.
Than you would need to create routes with

```
ip route add default via <router-ip / gateway-ip> dev <interface-name>
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0
```

and perhaps adjust the /etc/resolv.conf file

```
echo nameserver 192.168.1.1 >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

the latter nameserver is a google dns-server.

Comment: Thank you, I hope this answer will help me to fix my ubuntu 16.04, I'll try like this when I arrived home today. :)